# scipy.io.savemat module saves wrong structure mat

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, netcdf

My enviroment: window7 32bit anaconda spyder.

Here is my scripts,

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio 

s = 'http://tds.hycom.org/thredds/dodsC/GLBu0.08/expt_19.1/2012/3hrly'
f = Dataset(s, 'r')
v = f.variables

u = v['water_u'][0:1, 0:1, 1413:1651, 3838:4034]
u_xy = u[0,0,:,:]

sio.savemat('savemat.mat', {'mat_u': u})
loadmat_u = sio.loadmat('savemat.mat')['mat_u']
mat_u_xy = loadmat_u[0,0,:,:]

plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(u_xy)
plt.colorbar()

plt.figure(2)
plt.imshow(mat_u_xy)
plt.colorbar()
```

`figure(1)` and `figure(2)` are different each other. I think something
wrong with `scipy.io.savemat`

The figures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the `shape` of `u_xy` and `mat_u_xy`? what `dtype` are they? have you tried looking at the absolute difference between them?

Comment: shape are same. [8,39,238,196] 'time','depth','lat','lon'. type is floa32 same. convert mat may cause problem..i think.

Comment: how come your `shape` has four numbers when you sliced through the first two dimensions? Have you tried `squeeze`-ing `u_xy` before saving? what version of `numpy` are you using?

Comment: numpy vision is 1.9.2.

Comment: AFAIK there was a change in the way `numpy` arranges elements in memory. try `u_xy = u[0,0,:,:].copy(order='C')`

Comment: try that way, nothing changed. same image printed..

Comment: I try C and A,F,K ...but they are same..

Comment: can you post the resulting images? upload them to [tinypic](http://tinypic.com/) and post the link to the images.

Comment: What does `np.allclose(u._xy,mat_u.xy)` show?

Comment: I post a two image links, http://i59.tinypic.com/mx1qiu.png - figure(1)

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/2d0z7mx.png - figure(2). when you install netCDF4 module, you will sea that picture

Comment: np.allclose(u_xy, mat_u_xy) is print nothing. matrix. not array..